# best way to quickly rotate screen / change orientation?

Tags: display-rotation, orientation

I am using Ubuntu Studio 22.04, computer is connected to screen using HDMI.

Depending on the software being used (Ardour or VLC or software to manage my mixer...) I would like to have my desktop/screen rotated 90°...

I know that I can go to Settings/Displays and change the orientation, however I am looking for a quicker way to do so...

Ideally a function key or a shortcut :->

Any idea ?
Thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

First open your terminal

`xrandr`

execute this command to get to know which display you want to rotate. (perhaps 'HDMI-0')

Then try this out.

To rotate 90 degree counterclockwise
`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --rotate left`

To rotate 90 degree clockwise
`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --rotate right`

To bring it back to normal
`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --rotate normal`

Register the commands above to your favorite shortcut keys.

Comment: at one stage I also had to map the mapping for the touchscreen and mouse.and pen .. this was my script for Rotate Left  


xrandr --output eDP --rotate left &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP